# Centering image in a responsive fashion

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap v3.3.5. I just cannot center the image horizontally in a responsive fashion for some reason. Here is the code I am using.

```html
<div class="container">
      <div style="margin:0 auto;">
          <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
      </div>
</div>
```

I tried modifying the inline CSS code to

```css
margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
```

But it also didn't work. I researched and found out about .center-block and .img-responsive for Bootstrap but I guess it was removed (since I couldn't find anything related to said classes in my bootstrap.css). I am clueless right now.

Comment: Give 'text-align:center' to the parent of image.

Comment: Or use `container text-center` as your class.

Comment: img-responsive and center-block are still part of Bootstrap.

Comment: @TimLewis It worked.. but why `text-center`? Also, it is not changing the size of the image when on mobile. I've tried using `max-width: 100%` but it ruins the image size. How to make it responsive without altering its normal size, if you get me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the container surrounding the image and add the classes `.center-block` and `.img-responsive` to the image.

> Images in Bootstrap 3 can be made responsive-friendly via the addition of the `.img-responsive` class. This applies `max-width: 100%;`, `height: auto;` and `display: block;` to the image so that it scales nicely to the parent element.
>
> To center images which use the `.img-responsive` class, use `.center-block` instead of `.text-center`. [See the helper classes section](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#helper-classes-center) for more details about `.center-block` usage.
>
> ***source:*** https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#images

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="logo" />
</div>
```

Comment: Once I used Bootstrap's MaxCDN link, this code worked. Not really sure why the aforementioned CSS classes were in my bootstrap.css, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A block element takes up 100% of the width of its container if you don't specify a width value. Also, an image can be centered by using `text-align:center` on the nearest parent block element. This works because an image is considered a sort of inline element.

That said, Bootstrap has a `text-center` class that can be used here.